# How to dynamically change the period/delay of an interval for Angular / RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, intervals, subscribe

I want to dynamically change the period/delay of an interval, but unfortunately I am not too familiar with Angular, so I am stuck at this part.

Here is my current code:

```
timeDiffs : number[] = [] <== this is a preprocessed array with the timemeasurements in milliseconds

this.interval$ = interval(this.timeDiffs[this.intervalCounter++]).subscribe(() => {
    //some function calling here
     this.intervalCounter++; // next index for next iteration with a different time
})
```

Comment: what is `this.timeDiffs` ? please include all the code

Comment: @RachidO this.timeDiffs is an array of time measurements in ms. For example first one is 31000 and second one 33000 and third one 81000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just `concatMap()` and `timer()`. `concatMap()` guarantee the delays are invoked in correct order only when the previous one completes. `timer()` will emit once and complete after set delay.

```
import { from, concatMap, timer } from 'rxjs';

const timeDiffs = [1000, 1000, 3000, 1000];

from(timeDiffs)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(delay => timer(delay)),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nqyxqk?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Answer (score 2):

Use `BehaviorSubject`

```
const variable$ = new BehaviorSubject(1); //you can set initial value as per your need


this.variable$.pipe(
  switchMap(val => interval(125 * val),
  //now apply your various operators chain as per your need
  takeWhile(),...
  tap(),...
  map()...
).subscribe();

 this.variable$.next(newValue); //you can use this line to change variable  with a new value
```